# How to make this table?

Tags: tables

I've been struggling to get the following result:

```
Table N°: Title(1--footnote)
----------------------------
Category            Values
----------------------------
One                    200
Two                    100
Three                  410
----------------------------
Total                  710
----------------------------
Source: Author, 2013. [aligned with table float]
(1): Footnote text. [here]
```

How can I add the "Source: Author..." text there (maybe a "Notes:..." paragraph too), within the table float, and the footnote text right below?

Comment: Look at the `threeparttable` package

Comment: Alternatively, you can put the table in a `minipage`.

Comment: This question needs a more descriptive title...

Answer (score 3):

[image]

`MWE` with `ctable`:

```
% tmain.tex :
\begin{filecontents*}{tab1.tex}
\ctable[%
mincapwidth = 30mm,
footerwidth=80mm,
cap={Title},
caption = {Title \footnote{Footnote text}},
label = tab:1,
pos = ht,
left,
doinside = \scriptsize
]{SS}{\tnote[]{\textbf{Source:} Author, 2013. \\
\textbf{Notes:} Nam dui ligula,
fringilla a, euismod
sodales, sollicitudin vel,
wisi. Morbi auctor lorem
non justo. }
}{  \FL
{Category}& {Values}
%
\ML
%
{One  } & 200 \NN
{Two  } & 100 \NN
{Three} & 410 
\ML
Total & 710
\LL
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{ctable}
\renewcommand{\thempfootnote}{\arabic{mpfootnote}}
\begin{document}
\listoftables

\lipsum[1-5]

\input{tab1}

\lipsum[6-7]

\end{document}
```